# Realtime Database not showing in console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

The console window for Firebase Database just keeps spinning, waiting for results. This is a brand new setup; why should it not load?

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here. Did you try refreshing the page? Are there any errors showing in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I have the same issue, it's some kind of Corporate Firewall issue (works fine when not connected to company network).  Error is third_party/javascript/firebase/firebase_js_minified.jslib:176 WebSocket connection to 'wss://rplay-ae9e2.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing